# Is it true that 10 + 0.5 exactly equals to 10.5 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, floating-accuracy

In C++, according to

[Is hardcode float precise if it can be represented by binary format in IEEE 754?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646148/is-hardcode-float-precise-if-it-can-be-represented-by-binary-format-in-ieee-754),

10+0.5 should be exactly equals to 10.5 without rounding because both 10,0.5 and 10.5 are exact values in IEEE 754, which is different from the case in

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

But the first question is about C++, and javascript doesn't have integer type, so I would like to know if the case about exact values also applies in javascript.

Comment: It is true for Javascript as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605960/1266600) which cites the standard specifying JS's adherence to IEEE 754.