# If x, y, and a are numbers with integer values, does x/y round to the same value as (x*a)/(y*a)?

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, division, ieee-754

According to [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), I know 0.1 cannot represent exactly in floating point numbers and will be rounded to some values.

According to [Is hardcode float precise if it can be represented by binary format in IEEE 754?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646148/is-hardcode-float-precise-if-it-can-be-represented-by-binary-format-in-ieee-754), some numbers with integers values (e.g.:1,2,10...) can be represented perfectly (no rounding errors).

So my question is, if x ,y and a are values with integers, does x/y rounds to the same value as (x * a)/(y * a)?

For example, does 1/10 rounds to the values same as 10/100, as well as 123/1230?

Comment: For those simple examples, yes of course, but I'm not sure whether it's still the case once `xa`/`ya` become larger than 2^51

Comment: *"numbers with integers values (e.g.:1,2,10...) can be represented perfectly (no rounding errors)"* Only within the range `-Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - 1` through `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1`. Outside that range, integers are indeed rounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> numbers with integers values (e.g.:1,2,10...) can be represented perfectly (no rounding errors)

Only within the range `-Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - 1` (-9,007,199,254,740,992) through `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1` (9,007,199,254,740,992), inclusive. Outside that range, integers are indeed rounded:

```js
var n = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
console.log("n     =", n);
console.log("n + 1 =", n + 1);
console.log("n + 2 =", n + 2); // rounds
```

> For example, does 1/10 rounds to the values same as 10/100, as well as 123/1230?

For those sorts of examples, I think you'll end up with the same value, yes. But there are two things related to this worth mentioning:

1. I don't think JavaScript allows this, but some implementations that otherwise use IEEE-754 numbers allow *intermediate* values within a calculation with more precision than can be held by the format, and thus by the inputs and outputs of the calculation. [Java, for instance, has both "loose" and "strict" floating-point (the `strictfp` keyword and related runtime flags), where "loose" allows intermediate values with more precision and strict does not (for interoperability).] So in a "loose" FP environment and a sufficiently-complex calculation, if an implementation holds intermediate values in a more-precise form, the results can be slightly different from if every stage of the calculation were handled with rounding to the format's constraints. But again, I can't find anything in the JavaScript spec allowing that other than related to [some trigonometric functions](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function-properties-of-the-math-object), and I don't think that would apply to your simple division examples above even if it did.
2. As mentioned above, the magnitude of a decimal number can affect whether it's held precisely (0.1 isn't, 1 is, 9,007,199,254,740,993 isn't). But within the whole numbers in the range discussed above, since they're all held perfectly, the inputs will be precisely what they look like.

> If `x`, `y` and `a` are number with integer values, does `x/y` rounds to the same value as `(x*a)/(y*a)`?

That's a slightly different question, and it depends on the magnitude of the numbers. If the result of `x*a` or the result of `y*a` takes the value out of the range discussed at the beginning of this answer, you may get a different result for those expressions. So with large-ish integers, potentially no, they may not have the same result:

```js
var x = 945127356192545;
var y = 123456789012345;
var a = 27;

var r1 = x/y;
console.log("x/y         =", r1);
var r2 = (x*a)/(y*a);
console.log("(x*a)/(y*a) =", r2);
console.log("same?", r1 == r2);
```

Comment: i confirm 1. javascript does not offer higher precision during calculation. there are loads of pseudo random generators that had to keep that fact in mind.

Comment: @GottZ: Yeah, it's fairly clear from the more-recent specs, which say quite clearly (for instance, for [division](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-applying-the-div-operator)) that the result *"...is computed and rounded to the nearest representable value using IEEE 754-2008 round to nearest, ties to even mode."*

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Right. I don't think what's there says that it does. It says *implementations*, not specification. But let me edit to try to make it even more clear.